# Toggle button not working for navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, togglebutton

I am implementing a Navigation Drawer for my android application. I got the drawer to work by dragging from the side, but the home/toggle button on the action bar doesn't change to the icon I want and doesn't respond to clicks, thou the onDrawerClosed and onDrawerOpened methods defined in it are called.
My code is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/loadingFragment"
        android:name="com.whostr.clients.android.LoadingFragment" />

    <fragment 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/eventFragment"
        android:name="com.whostr.clients.android.EventDisplayFragment"/>

    <fragment 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/emptyFragment"
        android:name="com.whostr.clients.android.EmptyView"/>



<!--  Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width = "240dp"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity = "start"
    android:choiceMode = "singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight = "1dp"
    android:divider = "@android:color/transparent"
    android:background="#111"
    />
```

And in the activity I have the following code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedDataInstace)
{
    super.onCreate(savedDataInstace);
    setContentView(R.layout.eventdisplay);

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //get fragments by id
    fragments[EVENT_VIEW]= fm.findFragmentById(R.id.eventFragment);
    fragments[LOADING] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.loadingFragment);
    fragments[EMPTY_VIEW] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.emptyFragment);


    menuList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuArray);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawwer_open, R.string.drawer_closed)
                        {
                            /*
                             * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state
                             */
                            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
                            {
                                Log.d("drawerToggle", "Drawer closed");
                                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                                invalidateOptionsMenu(); //Creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                            }

                            /*
                             * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state
                             */
                            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
                            {
                                Log.d("drawerToggle", "Drawer opened");
                                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                                getActionBar().setTitle("NavigationDrawer");
                                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                            }
                        };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    //Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, menuList));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Log.d("navigationDrawer", "Clicked on an item");
        }

    });


    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    //Hide the event view
    transaction.hide(fragments[EVENT_VIEW]);
    transaction.hide(fragments[EMPTY_VIEW]);
    transaction.commit();

    AsyncTask<String, Void, EventResponseCollection> task = new GetEventsNearByAsyncTask().execute();
    try {
        if(task != null)
            events = task.get().getItems();

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        Log.d("viewEvent", "Error when retrieving task details " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if(events == null)
    {
        //show create your own event fragment
        changeFragment(EMPTY_VIEW);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("viewEvent", "I have " + events.size());
        //show proper fragment with the first event displayed
        currentEvent = events.get(eventIndex);
        ((EventDisplayFragment) fragments[EVENT_VIEW]).updateFragment(currentEvent);
        changeFragment(EVENT_VIEW);
    }
}

    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    Log.d("onOptionsItemSelected", "In the on item select");
    //Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    //true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        Log.d("onOptionsItemSelected", "Clicked on action bar item");
        return true;
    }

    //Handle your other action bar items...

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on what I can do? I've tried all solutions I found online to make this work, but apparently I'm out of luck and nothing seems to be working :(

Answer (score 19):

You have to add something like this in your Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    return drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I already overwrote that method, but it never get's called for some reason :(.I've added that method's code in the previous post.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me, its almost like the previous post

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
      } }
```

Comment: This is more in line with the Android Drawer Design Guidelines. Also, if it makes it to the end of the method(without entering if), then it should `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it was a small omission from my side, I forgot to include the following 2 lines of code:

`getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the similar issue. 
I hope this answer can help somebody facing similar problem.
Check for openDrawer attribute in your drawer layout

```
tools:openDrawer="start"
```

Also, check for drawer lock mode in your Activity and remove it, if you have accidentally locked drawer.

```
//drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Years later but anyway..... it could help anyone, when you have a layout with a Drawerlayout, the Drawer assumes that the First child is the view to overlap when shown and the Second child is the navigation panel. So in your case you could do something like...

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/loadingFragment"
    android:name="com.whostr.clients.android.LoadingFragment" />

<fragment 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/eventFragment"
    android:name="com.whostr.clients.android.EventDisplayFragment"/>

<fragment 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/emptyFragment"
    android:name="com.whostr.clients.android.EmptyView"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!--  Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
android:layout_width = "240dp"
android:layout_height = "match_parent"
android:layout_gravity = "start"
android:choiceMode = "singleChoice"
android:dividerHeight = "1dp"
android:divider = "@android:color/transparent"
android:background="#111"
/>
```

So in that way, the Drawer knows that the RelativeLayout is the view to overlap and the ListView is the left panel you want.

Also you have to do in the java code all the things you know.. setting up the toolbar, setting up the drawer indicating the toolbar, setting up the toogle etc... it's all in the comments.